# Unable to find element using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am executing 1000 tests using selenium webdriver.
for each test case I need to click "ID" element on the webpage.

I used `WebElement x = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='TEST']").click();` event.

But unfortunately for couple of test scenarios (2 or 3 out of 1000) it is throwing an error saying that "Unable to find an element". for the remaining test cases it is executing as usual.

I tried to use Try & Catch methods & Refresh the page but functionality is working as usual but performance is too slow.

Comment: Are you getting error on the same scenario's?

Comment: Performance will be slow because Selenium will launch a browser, and if you are doing this 1000 times, well it's obvious. What's the need for this? If it's just scraping some data from the page, Selenium is the *worst* tool for the job.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the ExpectedConditions class ( http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html ) 
Should be enough to just add some wait for the elementToBeClickable before clicking it.

Comment: so what is the best solutions for this. I tried to add Wait commands but not luck.

Comment: I have a solution for this. Solution is:      driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS); Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "Try & Catch methods & Refresh methods".
Selenium imitates a web browser itself, thus it is sometimes unstable.
1000 tests takes a lot of time, so make sure your computer doesn't fall asleep and don't disturb it's test process untill it is done.
Some tests will fail if you minimize the browser.

Comment: I added refresh and wait commands and it is working as expected.

Comment: Find out which page stuck, add some wait functions there. That is what i did before. The main  reason it stucks is that some page contents are not ready when you check the page.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend possibly increasing your implicit wait. Something like

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```